# Select multiple li's and it's first child using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Am trying to add a `onclick` event to the a tag of particular `li`'s which are under a `ul` with id `#nav`.

HTML Structure:

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#">link1</a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">link2</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">innerlink1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">innerlink2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">link3</a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">link4</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">innerlink1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">innerlink2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Jquery

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("ul#nav li").eq(1).children().first().click(function(){
        $(this).attr('onclick', 'return false;');
        return false;
    });
    $("ul#nav li").eq(5).children().first().click(function(){
        $(this).attr('onclick', 'return false;');
        return false;
    });
});
```

If you see, am writing jQuery twice to select the a element of `li` item which has got another `ul` inside and add `onclick` event to it. This is working fine. But is there way to reduce my code and make it more clean?

Comment: `$(this).attr('onclick', 'return false;');` What does this anti-pattern do in your code? Remove it.

Comment: What do you mean by anti-pattern? Could you please explain? I want to learn.

Comment: I meant it's a bad idea to set html event attributes using jQuery, apart from that html event attributes should be avoided according to [separation of concerns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/98734/what-is-separation-of-concerns) principle. In your code `return false` does what you want which is preventing the default action of the event and stopping propagation of it.

Comment: Thank you. I removed the event attribute. I'll go through the separation of concerns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you don't want the *li* that contains an *ul* child to fire the click event so i think it would be like this

```
$('#nav li:has(>ul)').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('click');
});
```

fiddle can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/552T4/3/

Comment: Oh wait, my innerlinks are not working now. I tried "$('#nav li:has(>ul)').children().first()" but again this is applying only for the first li.

Comment: ok, correct me if I'm wrong, but do you want to stop the click event on the "li" elements or "a" elements? If it is for the "a" elements here is the revised fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/552T4/6/

Answer (score 0):

Hey you may be looking for this:

```
    $("ul#nav li:has(>ul)")
```

Comment: Loved this one. But same as first solution. It is working for the a tag of first li.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("ul#nav li:eq(1),ul#nav li:eq(5)").children().click(function(){
   e.preventDefault();
   var youClicked=$(this).text();
   alert(youClicked);

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But this is returning only the first link.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#nav > li").each(function(){
        $(this).find('a').attr('onclick', 'return false;');
    });    
});
```

Below is fiddle of this.

[Js Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M3xZL/)

In above i apply "onclick" event to all anchor. if you want to apply only that li which has child ul then the code is something like this.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#nav > li").each(function(){
        if($(this).find('ul').length>0)
        {
           $(this).find('a').attr('onclick', 'return false;');
        }
    });    
});
```

below is the link for Li with Ul element selected.

[li with ul onclick](http://jsfiddle.net/M3xZL/2/)

Comment: Now you're applying that `onclick` to _all_ `#nav > li a` elements. That's _all_ anchors, not just the ones the OP wants.

Comment: @Cerbrus yes i apply all the anchor. if you want only first then also it can be done by using first. i update my answer please check it.

Comment: The OP has more specific requirements than just "all anchors"

Comment: @Cerbrus You can check my updated answer. i already change my answer.

Comment: @Cerbrus yes i know but i know there is two way to achieve this task. There are always more then one way to achieve any task. :) btw thanks

Answer (score -1):

Yea, Add ID's to the elements you need:

HTML Structure:

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#">link1</a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" id="liOne">link2</a>
        <ul>
            <li>innerlink1</li>
            <li>innerlink2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">link3</a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" id="liTwo">link4</a>
        <ul>
            <li>innerlink1</li>
            <li>innerlink2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Jquery

```
$("#liOne, #liTwo").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

Or even a class, instead of `id`'s.

This way, you only have to add the id / class attributes to the elements you want the click event to be handled on, instead of traversing the DOM like that.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Unfortunately I cannot add ids as the li's come from a loop.

Comment: @user3531929: Ah, that's a shame :P
Also, could the person that downvoted this answer please explain why? If I made a mistake, I'd like to learn from it.
While this may not be the solution for the OP, it is for use-cases where the user has the ability to influence how the HTML is structured.